# Special logic\algorithm in Shopping Cart

Tags: c#, algorithm, shopping-cart

I am implementing a site that has a shopping cart in c#.

Lets say I have these products in my database

product A price 50 
Product B price 50
Product C price 50
Product D price 50

user can add these products to his cart.

Now there is an offer running.
User can buy 3 pieces of product A or product B (any combination of these- example 2 of productA & 1 of product B  or all 3 of product A) and he will get one piece free.

(so in this example if he buys 3 pieces he has to pay 100 , 4 then pay 150 & 5 pieces  then he has to  pay 200 , 6 pieces also 200 )

How do I get an algorithm\pseudocode to implement this ?

Man problem lies that the products can beadded in any order so for example the produst are added in this order
 A,A,A
 or
 2A,B
 or 
 A,C,D,B,A
or
A,C,C,A

2A means that he added 2 pieces of product A in one action.
(in last case he will not avail that offer)

Please tell me what will be the easiest way to solve this ?
Can anyone point to some code where such thing is solved

Comment: There is one more complication . there is another set of offer which says if you buy 5 of A then you get 2 free.

Answer (score 2):

Get the total number of product A and product B being purchased and then just divide by 3 to see how many products are free.
EG.

```
int cost = 50;
int a = numOfProductA();
int b = numOfProductB();
int total = a + b;
int totalFree = total/3;
int totalCost = (total - totalFree)*cost;
```

There may be a move efficient way to do this, though more info would be good :) Like is getting the number of A or B difficult? Some code showing what you have already tried would be good.

EDIT: In response to your comment, it would be very similar logic. I won't give you code because I'm sure you can figure it out yourself from my previous example, and that would help you learn a lot better :) However, roughly, I would find the instances of 5 A first, then remove them from the number of purchases, then figure out the 3 A or B free items.
(eg. if 7 A and 1 B, find that 5 A's exist and give two free then calculate left over, so 2 A and 1 B to calculate the second offer)

Comment: Hi Nashi Thank you for your comment , added a comment in the original question.

Comment: Yes it did, thank you, I will try to extend on your idea a bit

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help you:

Example deal:  Buy 4 of **PRODUCT_A** get 2 of **PRODUCT_B** free

Variables:

- `numSkuRequired`: number of products required for deal to work(in this case 4)
- `skuRequired`: the product required for deal to work(in this case **PRODUCT_A**'s identifier, sku/id or something)
- `numSkuFree`: number of products to be given as free(in this case 2)
- `skuFree`: the product that is given away for free(in this case **PRODUCT_B**'s identifier, sku/id or something)
- `quantityLookupRequired`: **PRODUCT_A**'s summed quantity in cart, default `false`
- `quantityLookupFree`: **PRODUCT_B**'s summed quantity in cart, default `false`
- `quantityFree`: final result that we're looking for to calculate the total amount, number of free products(**PRODUCT_B**), default `0`
- `price`: price of **PRODUCT_B**, default `0`
- `discount`: total discount amount, default `0`

Steps

1. find sum of PRODUCT_A in cart, save in variable `quantityLookupRequired`
2. ensure that `quantityLookupRequired` is `>=` `numSkuRequired`
3. find sum of PRODUCT_B in cart, save in variable `quantityLookupFree`
4. ensure that `quantityLookupFree` is `>=` `numSkuFree`
5. find price of PRODUCT_B and save in variable `price`
6. loop(see below) to find `quantityFree` (the editor isn't allowing me to make this look much better sorry).
7. `discount` will be `quantityFree * price`

`for(int i = 0; i < numSkuRequired + numSkuFree; i <= quantityLookupRequired + quantityLookupFree; i += (numSkuRequired + numSkuFree))
    {
        quantityFree += numSkuFree;
    }
    while(quantityFree % numSkuFree != 0)/* don't allow partial discounts */
    {
        quantityFree--;
    }
    discount = quantityFree * price;`

Note: a slightly different approach is taken when the deal only includes 1 product(Buy 4 of **PRODUCT_A** get 2 of **PRODUCT_A** free)

Comment: What is that slightly different approach?